# After opening my application once, it updates automatically and opens its own app

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder, electron-react-boilerplate

I have developed an application using react and electron. And everything works great. When I package it, the application opens. However, when the app is open, the notification comes. It is automatically updated to version 3.0.2. Then, when I run my application again, the landing page of the electron-react-boilerplate application comes up. How can I get past this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. new AppUpdater() in main.dev.ts; The function was causing automatic updates. Disabling the code fixed it, thanks. Hope it helps others too